# Use complete induction to prove that $a_n < 2^n$ for every integer $n \geq 2$

Tags: induction

Define the sequence of integers $a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$ as follows

$$ a_i =
\begin{cases} 
      i+1 & 0 \leq i \leq 2 \\
      a_{i-1} + a_{i-2} + 2a_{i-3} & i > 2 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

Use complete induction to prove that $a_n < 2^n$ for every integer $n \geq 2$

I will prove $a_n < 2^n, \forall n \geq 2$ by using complete induction

Base Case: Three cases $n = 2, 3, 4$

let $n = 2$

$a_{n} = a_{2} = 2 + 1 = 3 < 4 = 2^2 = 2^n$ By definition, and holds

let $n = 3$

$a_{n} = a_{3} = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6 < 8 = 2^3 = 2^n$ By definition, and holds

let $n = 4$

$a_{n} = a_{4} = 4 + 3 + 2 = 9 < 16 = 2^4 = 2^n$ By definition, and holds

Inductive step: let $n > 4$. Suppose $a_j < 2^j$ whenever $2 \leq j < n$. [Inductive hypothesis]

What to prove: $a_n < 2^n$

$a_{n} = a_{i-1} + a_{i-2} + 2a_{i-3}$ [By definition]

$< 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3+1}$ [By Inductive hypothesis]

$= 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2}$

$= 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2 + 1}$

$= 2^{n-1 + 1}$

$= 2^n$

as wanted.

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part is fine. But the base case is not just the $n=2$ case. You should have checked it for $n=0$, and $n=1$ too.

Comment: But it doesn't hold for $n = 0$ or $n = 1$?

Comment: You are right. My mistake. But the you should have checked it for $n\in\{2,3,4\}$. Because only then will your inductive proof shows that it works for $n=5$.

Comment: I'm confused why. Why three numbers? And I thought the base case for recurrence functions was just so we can use "$a_{i-1} + a_{i-2} + 2a_{i-3}$" part but that part holds for all $i > 2$ so wouldn't going all the way to $n = 5$ be redundant?

Comment: Three numbers because each $a_i$ is defined from the **three** previous terms.  So, in order to prove it it holds for $a_5$, you must know that it holds for $a_2$, $a_3$, and $a_4$.